# GoToStateAction trigger doesn't work inside DataTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datatemplate which consists of a button with visual states inside of it. The button has defined ControlTemplate as grid with content presenter, and then inside the button there is defined content. I want to change visual states when bound data changes, but it seems to not work. If instead I use normal datatriggers to change visual properties directly it works.

Visual states would be easier in my use case though. I'm not sure if the propblem is with the visual states (are they somehow incorrectly defined, even though they were added via Blend?) or if the Interaction.Triggers do not work, or if the GoToStateAction doesn't work?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UpgradeElementDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type commonData:UpgradeItemViewModel}" >
            <Button x:Name="MainButton" Style="{StaticResource ButtonWithSoundStyle}"
                Command="{Binding CommandToInvoke}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BoughtState">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Bought">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{StaticResource HDC-Yellow}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Available"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="NotAvailable">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.5"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <b:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBought}" Value="True">
                        <b:GoToStateAction StateName="Bought"/>
                    </b:DataTrigger>
                    <b:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanBeBought}" Value="True">
                        <b:GoToStateAction StateName="Available"/>
                    </b:DataTrigger>
                    <b:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsUnavailable}" Value="True">
                        <b:GoToStateAction StateName="NotAvailable"/>
                    </b:DataTrigger>
                </b:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
                <Canvas>
                    <Grid ClipToBounds="False" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Right="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{DynamicResource Typo-Darker}" CornerRadius="10" Height="80" Width="117" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Opacity="1"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Canvas>
            </Button>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <!-- this data trigger works properly and the color gets changed, so the value of IsBought is properly changing in the view model. -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBought}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Yellow}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have stemmed from the fact that my VisualStateManager was inside the button and it couldn't properly change button's content elements? I've changed the arrangment so that button's contents are instead inside the control template and moved visualstate and the triggers there as well. It seems to work properly now.